# Javascript: How to iterate through an array of values and create table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am fetching data from a server, I would like to iterate through the values and display them into the first column of the table. Any help that can steer me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Javascript

```
fetch(_____,{
}).then(data => {
    var mstone = data.MilName;

    var table = document.getElementById("milestone-table");
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    // var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    //var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    //cell1.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
    //cell2.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
    
    //Iterating through data values and trying to display onto table
    for(var i = 0; i < mstone.length; i++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
        cell.innerHTML = mstone[i]; 
    }

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Fetch Problem: " + err);
});
```

Comment: Can you show what `data.MilName` data looks like?

Comment: Move your `var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);` inside the `for` loop and you will get what you need.

Comment: @codemonkey that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the table in HTML without any of rows added, loop through the response data and add a row and cell for each item.

```js
const data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] // Dummy response data
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

data.forEach(item => {
  const tr = tbody.insertRow();
  tr.insertCell().innerText = item
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like below. Have nested loops (1 for rows and 1 for columns)

```js
fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    const results = resp.results;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");

    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var row = table.insertRow(j);
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center; border: 1px solid blue;");
        cell.innerHTML = Object.values(results[j])[i];
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<table id="table" style="border: 1px solid grey"></table>
```